# Adjusting the vertical position of labels in a SwatchLegend

Tags: legending, alignment

How do I adjust the vertical position of labels in a SwatchLegend?

The simple command `SwatchLegend[{{col1, col2}},{{txt1, txt2}}]` generates something like shown in the image below.

[image: Mis-aligned labels]

The dashed line (added manually) is to show the height discrepancy. I have fiddled with `LegendMarkerSize` but that did not help. Is there a simple way to vertically align the text such that it appears around the middle of the swatch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On my machine/version, the labels look like they are aligned pretty much dead center. (Mac 12.5.1, MMA 13.1). I think you can probably fiddle with LabelStyle or styling applied to the label text itself. LegendMarkerSize might also have an impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using low-level `AdjustmentBox`:

```
Manipulate[
 SwatchLegend[{{col1, 
     col2}}, {RowBox[{AdjustmentBox[#, 
         BoxBaselineShift -> shift]}] & /@ {1, 2}}
   ] // DisplayForm
 ,
 {{shift, 0}, -0.5, 0.5}
 , ContentSize -> {100, 70}
 ]
```

[image]